# Silence all Powershell output

Tags: powershell

We have a Powershell script that gives some helpful output, but we don't want users to always see this and would like it to be silent at all times when called in a certain environment.  This script calls other scripts, if that matters.

I've tried doing something like `$silence = & G:\scripts\functions.ps1 >$null`, but I still get output.

What can I do to silence ALL output that comes from `functions.ps1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it sounds like you're dealing with output from more than one data stream! If it were me I'd redirect all streams to the output stream and then get it going to $null.

If the stream discussion sounds like gibberish, or my answer doesn't meet your needs check out this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx

`.\script.ps1 *> $null`

Comment: And just to clarify that * symbol I used only appears in V3 and above.

Comment: The `*>` was the key.  Thanks!